# How to read aloud c++ expressions with the input/output operators?

Tags: c++

I feel pretty stupid, but I'm just starting to learn c++ after coming from other languagues, and I cannot for the life of me comprehend statements that use "<<" and ">>".  I know it is simple, but it confuses me every time.

The book I'm using made a really good recommendation to read const declarations from right to left.  Is there any similar method for "<<" and ">>"?

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting.  I think I actually think in code, not English, so I don't have this translation problem.  Weird.

Answer (score 3):

i like to say "gets".

```
cout << "some expression = " << expr << endl;
```

i'd say that as "cout gets some expression, gets expr, gets endull." similarly if you're reading from a stream, it's your variable that "gets" a value from the input...

Answer (score 3):

On the phone, back when I was a consultant frequently needing to "read aloud" C++ code to clients' employees on the phone, I (explaining once or twice, then they got it) read "input" operator `>>` as "absorb" and "output" operator `<<` as "emit".  "get" and "put" would work just as well if they didn't conflict with alas-too-common other uses.  But that doesn't seem to have much to do with right-to-left vs left-to-right, just with your Q's title about "reading aloud" -- "cin absorb x" or "essteedee cout emit blach emit essteedee endl" kinds of "reading code aloud" (e.g. on the phone)!-)

Answer (score 2):

I typically read them from left to right, like so:

```
cout << setw(6) << val << endl;

"Send to cout, with a width of 6, the contents of val, and then end the line and flush."
```

or

```
cin >> val;

"Get from cin the contents of val."
```

It does take a little bit of special consideration in that you can't just say specific words for each token.

Answer (score 2):

To understand C++, you have to understand that C++ has many of the most powerful tools to build abstractions. `cout` is nothing but a [`stream`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507747/can-you-explain-the-concept-of-streams/507829#507829). So, it is very acceptable to mimic the concept of stream.

For example,

```
std::cout << "hey"; // '<<' is something like the direction of the `data`
```

throws things in the stream with the same syntax and conventions, infact there is only one syntax for all types.

Also,

```
std::cin >> number;
```

extracts the next value of the type specified by `number` and put it in `number`.

It just make sense when you think about streams in C++. You can see this in most modern C++ libraries, for example with `Boost` you can do this:

```
boost::filesystem::path mypath;
....
mypath = mypath/filename;
```

The division operator is replaced with '`/`' or '`\`' depending on the system you are targeting :)

Answer (score 2):

I never thought too much about it but I suppose you could say "Streams to" or "Streams from" eg.

```
cout << mysting << endl;
```

"cout streams from mystring streams from endline"

```
cin >> myvalue;
```

"cin streams to myvalue"

I just made that up but it makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy enough the object that the symbol is pointing to on the receiving end.  So:

```
cout << "Enter First Name: ";

    cin >> FirstName;
```

in this code, cout in usually stdout and is "receiving" the characters "Enter First Name", FirstName which is presumably a variable is "receiving" the data from cin which is probably stdin.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to distinguish the two is like so.

```
cout << "Some fancy string...";
```

In this example your are taking a string and sending it to the world (monitor).

```
cin >> x;
```

In that one you take an value from the world (keyboard) and save the it into x.
Hence the direction Value >> X.