# Understanding Streams and their lifetime (Flush, Dispose, Close)

Tags: c#, stream, dispose, flush

Note: I've read the following two questions already:

[Can you explain the concept of streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507747/can-you-explain-the-concept-of-streams)

[C# using streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404303/c-using-streams)

I'm coding in C#

1. In almost all code samples that use streams, .Dispose(), .Flush(), .Close() are almost always called.

   - In the concept of a stream, what does accomplish?
   - If I don't dispose a stream that I stored in a variable, is my application leaking somewhere?
   - Why do I need to call any of these functions? I've seen code samples that don't do this and still get the job done (without an **apparent** breakage)

I'm currently building a class in my application that contains a primary method (lets call it `GetStream()`) that returns a stream via `myWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()`

The primary method `GetStream()` returns a `Stream` object that can be used for any operation that requires a stream (StreamReader, Bitmap() etc.).

Is there a way to have the stream Disposed of automatically after its last use (garbage collected?) without forcing anyone that calls `.GetStream()` to manually dispose of it?

As you can probably tell, my questions are vague and general. My understanding of streams is not solid, so any links to helpful articles that offer a more in-depth look at streams than a SO question can offer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Disposing a stream closes it (and probably doesn't do much else.)  Closing a stream flushes it, and releases any resources related to the stream, like a file handle.  Flushing a stream takes any buffered data which hasn't been written yet, and writes it out right away; some streams use buffering internally to avoid making a ton of small updates to relatively expensive resources like a disk file or a network pipe.

You need to call either `Close` or `Dispose` on most streams, or your code is incorrect, because the underlying resource won't be freed for someone else to use until the garbage collector comes (who knows how long that'll take.)  `Dispose` is preferred as a matter of course; it's expected that you'll dispose all disposable things in C#.  You probably don't have to call `Flush` explicitly in most scenarios.

In C#, it's idiomatic to call `Dispose` by way of a `using` block, which is syntactic sugar for a try-finally block that disposes in the finally, e.g.:

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path))
{
    // ...
}
```

is functionally identical to

```
FileStream stream;

try
{
    stream = new FileStream(path);
    // ...
}
finally
{
    if (stream != null)
        stream.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: The finally should be: `if (stream is IDisposable) ((IDisposable) stream).Dispose ();

Comment: It's a compiler error to use 'using' on a variable that's not known to be IDisposable. However it should technically be: if (stream != null) stream.Dispose();

Comment: In many cases it's a good idea to explicitly close a stream even if one also calls `Dispose`.  Closing a stream may require performing actions that cannot be guaranteed to succeed; implementations of `Close` will generally throw an exception when such problems occur, while some `Dispose` implementations may stifle such exceptions (swallowing such exceptions is evil, but allowing them to propagate out of `Dispose` will often clobber a previous exception, which is also evil; implementations differ as to which evil is considered the lesser).

Comment: A `using` block directly takes advantage of the IDisposable interface, calling the `Dispose()` method on scope exit: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx